# changed jQuery Mobile's default icon set, work on browser, failed on device

Tags: android, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

in my application, I changed the jQuery-Mobile's default icon:

icons-18-white.png

CSS:

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
background-color: #000000 /*{global-icon-color}*/;
background-color: transparent /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-border-radius:              9px;
border-radius:                      9px;
}
```

This is the icon before I change:

[image]

This is the icon after I changed it:

[image]

when I test it under Chrome, it works fine, app is picking up the new icons.

[image]

But when I build it onto device, whether iOS or Android, they are still showing the old
arrow icons.

I've tried to delete the app and clean the project and rebuild. But it still does not pick up the new icon.

what's the potential problem is?

Comment: are you hosting files locally? jQM version?

Comment: yes. I am hosting JQM locally version number 1.3.1

Comment: are you modifying jQM.css or adding those styles in a separate stylesheet?

Comment: in a separate stylesheet. It is working in Chrome. App is picking up the new icons. But failed on device.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that iOS and Android phones deal with "icons-36-white.png", so you should include and change it as well.