# jQuery Mobile's icon changes not show in phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I initially asked this question: [changed jQuery Mobile's default icon set, work on browser, failed on device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22401542/765498), but later, I found this could be a phonegap issue.

Is there anyone who has experience in changing JQuery Mobile's default set in phonegap?

Check my other post about the problem description.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I added !important to the end and that works:

```
.ui-icon-customicon {
background-color: #000000 /*{global-icon-color}*/;
background-color: transparent /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png) !important/*{global-icon-set}*/;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-border-radius:              9px;
border-radius:                      9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom icon

```
.ui-icon-customicon {
    background-color: #000000 /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background-color: transparent /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius:              9px;
    border-radius:                      9px;
}
```

In html page

```
<a href="#" data-icon="customicon" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i suggest the same that i've already suggested in your previous question... It should help if you only need to change icons.
But if you now want to change styles of JQuery Mobile elements - than you can change styles of corresponding classes or use custom elements as Ved has already mentioned.